# Get PDO lastInsertId() after method called

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my code I use `methods` to insert data to `MySQL` database. The method then return either `true` or `false`.

If the `method` return `true` I would like to use `lastInsertId()` to run a second method.

Like

```
if($db->insertMethod($data)){
    $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->secondInsertMethod($lastId, $data2)
}
```

db.class.php

```
public function insertMethod($data) {
    $db = new DB();
    $insert = //Run SQL insert
    if($insert > 0 ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}

public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

In this case `$db->lastInsertId();` will return `0`. One workaround would be to have `insertMethod` to return this instead of just `true` but there must another way as well?

Answer (score 0):

Edited!

the solution is correct

The data2 is linked to the data ?

you can also make :

```
public function insertMethod($data, $data2) {
    $db = new DB();
    $insert = //Run SQL insert
    if($insert > 0 ) {
        $this->insertMethod(this->lastInsertId(), $data2);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

or if data2 is linked to the data

```
public function insertMethod($data) {
    $db = new DB();
    $insert = //Run SQL insert
    if($insert > 0 ) {
        $data2 = // get data2
        $this->insertMethod(this->lastInsertId(), $data2);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}

public function insertMethod($id, $data) {
    // your code...
}
```

or

```
public function insertMethod($data, $id = null) {
    $db = new DB();        
    if($id == null)
        // code to insert without id
    else { 
        $insert = //Run SQL insert
        if($insert > 0 ) {
            $data2 = // get data2
            $this->insertMethod($data2, this->lastInsertId());
        }
    }   
}
```

The solutions are correct. For you to see who you think is the most appropriate in your situation.

Comment: When calling from within the method with `return $this->lastInsertId();` its very meaningful. So the value is exactly what I want but its the way to get it outside of the method that I'm after.